# When The Parable of the Budding Fig Tree will fulfill?

Tags: parables, second-coming

In **Deuteronomy 8:8** it says that:

> אֶ֤רֶץ חִטָּה֙ וּשְׂעֹרָ֔ה וְגֶ֥פֶן וּתְאֵנָ֖ה וְרִמּ֑וֹן אֶֽרֶץ־זֵ֥ית
> שֶׁ֖מֶן וּדְבָֽשׁ׃

Which is the same as:

> a land of wheat and barley, of vines, **figs**, and pomegranates, a land
> of olive trees and honey;

concerning **figs** I'd like to know what is the meaning of the following:

> 32 Now learn a parable of the **fig tree**; When his branch is yet tender,
> and putteth forth **leaves**, ye know that **summer** is nigh: 33 So likewise
> ye, when ye shall see all **these things**, know that it is near, even at
> the doors. 34 Verily I say unto you, This **generation** shall not pass,
> till all these things be fulfilled. 35 Heaven and earth shall pass
> away, but my words shall not pass away.

What exactly does **summer** refer to, and **these things** and also **this generation** in order to understand exactly what period is implicit? How this event fits in the jewish calendar?

Comment: Please add the verse reference for the second passage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Jesus was talking about the Sukkot harvest at the end of the summer. The time when figs, grapes and other fruit were gathered. The time when the juice was extracted from those grapes.

The parable of the budding fig tree must be talking about the mass conversion of the Jews. Jesus cursed the fig tree as a sign of judgement of Jerusalem and Judea. The dead fig tree coming back to life will be in line with many prophecies, like Ezekiel 37 and Romans 11 to name just a couple. The tree was fruitless, but before Jesus' return it is going to bring the fruit.